# why Html form is not displaying over image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have designed one form below the image. Now, I want to display full responsive image in a background of the form.

I tried to code but the image is displaying inside the form rather than displaying a form on full width and height image.

Where is my mistake?

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 form-box">
<div class="formhold">

<form role="form" action="" method="post" class="f1" >

        <h3>Fill in the form to get Flight</h3>
        <div class="f1-steps">
                <div class="f1-progress">
                    <div class="f1-progress-line" data-now-value="16.66" data-number-of-steps="3" style="width: 16.66%;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="f1-step active">
                        <div class="f1-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                        <p>plan</p>
                </div>
                <div class="f1-step">
                        <div class="f1-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></div>
                        <p>schedule</p>
                </div>
            <div class="f1-step">
                        <div class="f1-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></div>
                        <p>people</p>

        </div>

            <div class="f1-step">
                        <div class="f1-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></div>
                        <p>about</p>

        </div>
    </div>

        <fieldset>
            <h4>I want to go:</h4>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="f1-first-name">From</label>
        <input type="text" name="f1-first-name" placeholder="From..." class="f1-first-name form-control" id="f1-first-name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="f1-last-name">To</label>
        <input type="text" name="f1-last-name" placeholder="To..." class="f1-last-name form-control" id="f1-last-name">
    </div>

    <div class="f1-buttons">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>


</form>
</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.formhold {

  background: url(images/334.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

form {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have the right idea.

I drew up a really quick code-pen mock up you can take a look at:

http://codepen.io/zsawaf/pen/vKRLAP

In summary your mistake was that you needed another container outside of the bootstrap columns that spans the entire page and holds a background image.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid cover-img">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- whatever you want your form container to span -->
        <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-container">
            <form>
              <input type="text"/>
              <input type="text"/>
              <input type="text"/>
              <input type="text"/>
              <input type="text"/>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

SCSS:

```
.cover-img {
  background-image: url(http://previews.123rf.com/images/9nong/9nong1404/9nong140400110/27534018-wood-chip-and-saw-dust-background-compressed-Stock-Photo.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.form-container {
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border-radius: 5px;
  form {
    margin: 20px 0;
    input {
      margin: 5px 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: superb!
That was the actual mistake, i was finding.
keep it up.
God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

So i'm not sure if that worked for you but the last example was. Adding a `wrapper` div around the form with the `container-fluid` class and applying the background to that:

```
.wrapper {
     background: url(images/334.jpg) no-repeat;
     background-position: top center;
     background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper container-fluid">
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 form-box">
<div class="formhold">

<form role="form" action="" method="post" class="f1" >

        <h3>Fill in the form to get Flight</h3>
        <div class="f1-steps">
                <div class="f1-progress">
                    <div class="f1-progress-line" data-now-value="16.66" data-number-of-steps="3" style="width: 16.66%;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="f1-step active">
                        <div class="f1-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                        <p>plan</p>
                </div>
                <div class="f1-step">
                        <div class="f1-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></div>
                        <p>schedule</p>
                </div>
            <div class="f1-step">
                        <div class="f1-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></div>
                        <p>people</p>

        </div>

            <div class="f1-step">
                        <div class="f1-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></div>
                        <p>about</p>

        </div>
    </div>

        <fieldset>
            <h4>I want to go:</h4>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="f1-first-name">From</label>
        <input type="text" name="f1-first-name" placeholder="From..." class="f1-first-name form-control" id="f1-first-name">
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QEmNNv) is the link to the latest jsFiddle.

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide Did you give the form element a width? I've updated my answer with a link to codepen.

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide Do you want the background image to cover the entire page background?

Comment: As it is now, it'll never be bigger than the bootstrap sized .form-box div it is in.

Comment: When you say full div, do you mean the full size of .form-box or the full browser window?

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide Like this: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dXmGvK) ?

Comment: Like the codepen? Then you need to add the background style to the body element. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117825/discussion-between-sinan-guclu-and-bc110402307-syed-zeeshan-haide).

Answer (score 0):

Like Sinan said, you need to give the form a width and height to match the image size.

I think you can take Sinan's code and combine it with this to expand the form's width and height to match the image size.

Let's say your image size is 1024x768, then:

```
form {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1024px;
  height:768px;
}
```

Comment: This solves the problem of the full width form box, but it isn't responsive.

Comment: yeah! It's not the responsive one and i am getting so many troubles in after implementing this piece of code

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
.formhold {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: inherit;
  background-image: url(images/334.jpg)
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-size: inherit;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```